# Iniciar uma ação com comando de voz igual o: "ok Google"

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando criar um sistema, para meu site, que inicie ações com comando de voz, mas sem precisar clicar em nada, a única coisa que o usuário vai ter que fazer e não tem jeito é habilitar o microfone. Estou usando a API SpeechRecognition e o mais próximo que consegui foi isso:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/teste.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn-gravar-audio">Gravar</button><br/><br/>
        <textarea id="textarea" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
</body>
</html>﻿
```

Javascrpit

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

if (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition) {

    var speech_api = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var gravar = new speech_api();
    gravar.continuous = false;
    gravar.interimResults = false;
    gravar.lang = "pt-BR";

    gravar.onresult = function (){
        gravar = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        console.log(gravar);

        if(gravar.toLowerCase() === "gravar"){
                   document.getElementById("btn-gravar-audio").click();
               }
    };

    gravar.start();

}

}, false);

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var btn_gravacao = document.querySelector('#btn-gravar-audio');

var transcricao_audio = '';
var esta_gravando = false;

var dicionario = {
"@": /\b arroba\b/gi,
".": /\b ponto\b/gi,
":": /\b dois pontos\b/gi,
",": /\b v[íi]rgula\b/gi,
"!": /\b exclamação\b/gi,
"?": /\b interrogação\b/gi
};

if (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition) {

    var speech_api = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var receber_audio = new speech_api();

    receber_audio.continuous = true;
    receber_audio.interimResults = true;
    receber_audio.lang = "pt-BR";

    receber_audio.onstart = function () {
        esta_gravando = true;
        btn_gravacao.innerHTML = 'Gravando! Parar gravação';
    };

    receber_audio.onend = function () {
        receber_audio.start();
        esta_gravando = false;
        btn_gravacao.innerHTML = 'Iniciar Gravação';
    };
    receber_audio.onresult = function (event) {
                var interim_transcript = '';

               for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
                   if(event.results[i].isFinal){
                       transcricao_audio += event.results[i][0].transcript; 
                   }else{
                       interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript; 
                   }

                   var resultado = transcricao_audio || interim_transcript;

                   console.log(resultado);

               }

               for (var substituto in dicionario) {
        resultado = resultado.replace(dicionario[substituto], substituto);
    }



               document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = resultado;

    };

    btn_gravacao.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (esta_gravando) {
            receber_audio.stop();
            return;
        }
        receber_audio.start();
    }, false);

} else {
    console.log("navegador não apresenta suporte a web speech api");
}
}, false);
```

Ao carregar a página o primeiro window.addEventListener roda. Ao falar "gravar", ativa o segundo e começa a rodar, então eu falo e escreve no textarea. até aí funcionando normal. O problema é que o primeiro window.addEventListener roda apenas por alguns segundos e depois para de rodar porque o SpeechRecognition fica um tempo e depois para de gravar. No segundo window.addEventListener o SpeechRecognition fica em looping infinito porque eu coloquei um receber_audio.start(); dentro do receber_audio.onend = function () e então força o SpeechRecognition a reiniciar novamente, mas no primeiro window.addEventListener quando eu tentei não funcionou, também tenho um outro problema que é se eu falar outra coisa diferente de gravar, já era! Eu vou ter que recarregar a página novamente para começar a gravar de novo, por isso não coloquei gravar.continuous = true; no primeiro window.addEventListener e sim false, mas preciso que assim que terminar de gravar, volte a gravar novamente. Se eu estiver fazendo muita ganbiarra me avisem. até agora não vi uma forma melhor de trabalhar com comando de voz (de graça) que usando o SpeechRecognition. O problema é que eu não tenho ideia de como o pessoal da google fez para fazer aquele comando "Ok google" quando ainda utilizavam no site deles. Eu só fiquei sabendo que tinha depois que tiraram e pelo que vi foi por que ninguém estava usando.

Comment: conforme citado aqui nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996350/speech-recognition-run-continuously) o reconhecimento de voz é forçado a parar após alguns segundos, deve ser um mecanismo de segurança para que nenhum site fique espionando indefinidamente o usuário. Eu te sugiro usar um timer `setTimeout(function() {...})` pra verificar se tua captura de voz ainda está rodando e, se não estiver, reinicia-la, reagendando a mesma no final do setTimeout.

Comment: Eu tentei utilizar o setTimeout e o setInterval também, mas parece que o o SpeechRecognition está bloqueando.

Comment: Essa [resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818154/webkitspeechrecognition-stops-recording-randomly) sugere usar o `setTimeout` pra parar o reconhecimento de voz (o que invocará o `.onend`) com um `.start()` no evento `.onend`

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse vídeo pode te dar uma Luz! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQV4Tq__KMA

Comment: Consegui resolver aqui pessoal. Obrigado pela ajuda. hugocsl já tinha visto esse video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


var audio = '';
var gravando = false;

if (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition) {

    var speech_api = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var gravar_audio = new speech_api();

    gravar_audio.continuous = false;
    gravar_audio.interimResults = false;
    gravar_audio.lang = "pt-BR";

    gravar_audio.onstart = function () {
        gravando = true;
    };

    gravar_audio.onend = function () {
        gravar_audio.start();
        gravando = false;
    };
    gravar_audio.onresult = function (event) {
                       audio = event.results[0][0].transcript; 
                   console.log(audio);



               if(audio.toLowerCase() === "gravar"){
                document.getElementById("btn-gravar-audio").click();
                gravar_audio.onend = function () {
                    gravando = false;
                };
               }
    };

        if (gravando) {
            gravar_audio.stop();
            return;
        }
        gravar_audio.start();

} else {
    console.log("navegador não apresenta suporte a web speech api");
}
}, false);
```